# Appending email body message

Tags: javascript, email

I am currently working on some easy javascript, wherein a user clicks a checkbox, and our email client will be brought up, ready to send an email.  I have all the information I need, and everything appears as it should when the email client is brought up, but I have a signiture to that email that is erased whenever I do the "?body=text" stuff.

I was wondering (as I am finding it difficult to find on my own) if there is a way to append text to an email through javascript, rather than replace the text.

Comment: i'm sorry but you can't control how the editor responds to the `mailto:` handler.

Comment: @DanielA.White I see, no wonder I couldn't find much on it.  Thanks for your help!